# How to find out what cipher parameters google cloud VPN uses for IKEv1 ?

Tags: networking, vpn, cisco, google-cloud-vpn

As per the google docs we have configured cisco ASA FTD vpn tunnel with supported phase 1 phase 2 ciphers  but connection not established . Status is "Initial Handshake "

In logs we could see phase 1 DH group mismatch from cisco end .

Ciphers which we used to configure tunnel - > https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/supported-ike-ciphers#ikev1-ciphers

Google promises they use above ciphers when we select IKEv1 but why it is not connecting & why we are getting DH group mismatch error in logs  . All the necessary VPN ports are open from both the ends .

Any help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

Since the CISCO device is behind the NAT , Hence CISCO VPN gateway must identify itself using the same public IP address of the NAT device .

Here Google cloud VPN is meeting  RFC7815 compliance but CISCO ASA FTD isn't RFC7815 compliance .
Due to that setting a device identity to an IP address different from the one the device is using (its internal address) is not supported in this specific device CISCO ASA FTD .

Thanks everyone .

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider move to the IKEv2, that it offers more options for ciphers.

Let me share some links that might help you with the issue.

Google has a several guides for VPN configuration per some vendors.

[Guides by vendors](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/interop-guides?hl=bg#interop_guides_by_vendor)

Also, you can check these links for VPN issues troubleshooting

[Troubleshooting for Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/support/troubleshooting)

If you are behind a NAT in your on-prem, try with this guide:

[Gateway behindNAT](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/resources/troubleshooting#gateways_behind_nat).

All the best.